# Using optimistic locks in C++ and memory order

Tags: c++, synchronization, locking, stdatomic, optimistic-locking

I'm wondering how 'optimistic locks' (as described e.g. here: [https://db.in.tum.de/~leis/papers/artsync.pdf](https://db.in.tum.de/%7Eleis/papers/artsync.pdf)) can be used in C++ with regard to non-atomic data and what memory orders should be used.

My understanding from the above paper is that following code will synchronize `t1` and `t2` and `t1` will either print both variables updated or none.

```
static constexpr uint64_t locked_bit = (1ULL << 63);

std::atomic<int> data1 = 0;
std::atomic<int> data2 = 0;
std::atomic<uint64_t> versioned_lock = 0;

int main() {
    std::thread t1([&]{
        restart:
        auto s = versioned_lock.load();
        if (s & locked_bit)
            goto restart;

        auto local_data1 = data1.load();
        auto local_data2 = data2.load();
        if (s == versioned_lock.load()) {
            // data has not been overwritten yet, can safely use local_data
            std::cout << local_data1 << " " << local_data2 << std::endl;
        } else {
            // possible race, local_data might be garbage?
        }
    });

    std::thread t2([&]{
        auto current_lock_version = versioned_lock.load();
        current_lock_version++;
        versioned_lock.store(current_lock_version | locked_bit);
        data1.store(1234);
        data2.store(4321);
        versioned_lock.store(current_lock_version);
    });

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

My questions are:

1. I this a valid C++ code with no UB?
2. Are my assumption about synchronization correct? Will `t1` actually print either "0 0" or "1234 4321"?
3. What memory orders should be used for reading/writing to `versioned_lock`? Should it be `memory_order_seq_cst` or can it be something less restrictive? Will it work also if `data1` and `data2` are non-atomic (just `int` or even some more complex data type) and does it affect the required memory order (or maybe there is a need for atomic_thread_fence)?

Comment: When thread-1 is launched, ```if (s & locked_bit)``` can be reached before thread-2 is launched.

Comment: Yes, and that's fine, I only want to protect t1 from printing inconsistent data (e.g. data1 with old value but data2 with new value)

Comment: When I run your program in a loop, it sometimes takes the error "else" branch  with synchronized values (https://godbolt.org/z/a4rGdPxf8) and it just caught an error with 0 and 4321 but its as rare as 1 in 200k tries. Can be a lot more frequent in some other system though.

Comment: Tried again, got 0 4321 twice in a row. Looks like ~1 in 150k now.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I see that you moved the printing code to the `else` branch. In such case this makes sense, since the `else` branch is taken in case of detecting a possible race. There should be no inconsistencies in the first branch, however.

Comment: I moved it back to the first branch, same error: https://godbolt.org/z/Wv9r6MsYY : ```1234 0``` instead of ```0 4321``` and it happened in third try (1 in 90000). Tried again, twice in a row again, 1 in 15000 now. I think server load changes the frequency.

Comment: You are right, I also got similar output. Any ideas why? My understanding was that `t1` sees modifications to all variables in the exact same order in which they were made, so in case of any races, we should take the second branch. Is this not correct? Is this UB?

Comment: Ok, I did a very stupid mistake... In `t2` there should be `versioned_lock.store(current_lock_version | locked_bit);` instead of `versioned_lock.store(current_lock_version & locked_bit);` I've fixed the code snippet. @huseyintugrulbuyukisik this was the source of those errors. If you run the code now, it should always print consistent values.

Comment: Maybe using ```std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);``` and its release versions on versioned-atomic could help as if they were a mutex.

Comment: I'm not sure about the acquire/release. I think for load with acquire we have a guarantee that no other loads will be reorder **before** the atomic load but here, we need loads for `data` to not be reorder before the first load of versioned_lock and after the second load of versioned_lock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a valid C++ code with no UB?

I think so.  The usual way to get UB in such a program is a data race,
but that can only happen when a non-atomic variable is written
concurrently, and every shared variable in this program is atomic.

> Are my assumption about synchronization correct? Will t1 actually print either "0 0" or "1234 4321"?

Yes.  All the loads and stores in this version are `seq_cst`, so they
occur in some total order, which I will use < to denote.  Let L1, L2 denote the two loads of
`versioned_lock` in t1, and S1, S2 the two stores in t2.

If S1, S2 both occur before L1, then both the new values will be seen
and we print `1234 4321`, which is fine.  If S1, S2 both occur after L2 then we
print `0 0`, which is also fine.  If either S1 or S2 occurs in between
L1 and L2, then L1 and L2 return different values and we do not print
anything, which again is fine.

The only ordering that remains is S1 < L1 < L2 < S2.  In this case L1
returns the value with the locked bit set, and so we restart the loop
instead of printing.

> What memory orders should be used for reading/writing to
> versioned_lock? Should it be memory_order_seq_cst or can it be
> something less restrictive?

I *think* that the following suffices:

```
static constexpr uint64_t locked_bit = (1ULL << 63);

std::atomic<int> data1 = 0;
std::atomic<int> data2 = 0;
std::atomic<uint64_t> versioned_lock = 0;

int main() {
    std::thread t1([&]{
        restart:
        auto s = versioned_lock.load(std::memory_order_acquire); // L1
        if (s & locked_bit)
            goto restart;

        auto local_data1 = data1.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        auto local_data2 = data2.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);    // AF
        if (s == versioned_lock.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) { // L2
            // data has not been overwritten yet, can safely use local_data
            std::cout << local_data1 << " " << local_data2 << std::endl;
        } else {
            // possible race, local_data might be garbage?
        }
    });

    std::thread t2([&]{
        auto current_lock_version = versioned_lock.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        current_lock_version++;
        versioned_lock.store(current_lock_version | locked_bit, std::memory_order_relaxed); // S1
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release); // RF
        data1.store(1234, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        data2.store(4321, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        versioned_lock.store(current_lock_version, std::memory_order_release); // S2
    });

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

That is, the accesses to `versioned_lock` that clear and test the locked
bit must be release and acquire, the stores of the data must be
preceded by a release fence, and the loads of the data followed by an
acquire fence.  Intuitively, this should keep the data accesses from leaking out from between the lock accesses that protect them. (You could also make all the stores of the data
be release and then drop the release fence, but that would be unnecessarily
strong: we do not care if the two data stores get reordered with each
other.  It would make a bigger difference if we had many more data elements.  The same applies to the option of making the data loads acquire.)

To prove that this works, notice that the two results we must avoid are `1234 0` and `0 4321`.  So suppose that the load of `data1` returns `1234` (the case when `data2` returns `4321` is equivalent).  Since this is the value that was stored by t2, the release fence (RF) synchronizes with the acquire fence (AF).  Now S1 is sequenced before RF, and AF is sequenced before L2, so we conclude that S1 happens before L2.  Thus L2 cannot return 0; it either returns `locked_bit` or `1`.

If L1 returns a different value from L2 then we will not print.  If  L1 returns `locked_bit` we also will not print.  The one remaining case is that L1 and L2 both return 1.  In this case, L1 has read the value written by S2, and L1/S2 are acquire/release, so S2 synchronizes with L1.  The data stores are sequenced before S2, and L1 is sequenced before the data loads, so both data stores happen before both data loads.  Therefore we see both the new values, and print `1234 4321`.

> Will it work also if data1 and data2 are non-atomic (just int or
> even some more complex data type)?

No, that will not work at all.  Nothing in this algorithm prevents the
stores and loads of `data1, data2` from conflicting; it's just that
when they do conflict, our tests of the versioned lock tell us not to
use the data.  But if they were not atomic, the conflicting stores and
loads would be a data race, causing undefined behavior whether we use
the data or not.